# Closed form for a difficult integral

Tags: improper-integrals, closed-form

Can any one help to find the closed form for this difficult integral, it seems very tough to me.

$$\large{\int}_0^\infty\small \dfrac{\log^2\left|\cot(\dfrac{ax}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4})\right|}{x^4+4}dx$$

Comment: Forgive me, but this is completely unintelligible to me. Can you use MathJax?

Comment: Please use MathJax, this is very strange.

Comment: how to use Math Jax?

Comment: You should learn how to type the equations correctly. Please take a look at my edit. More information about MathJax can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable information, I will learn to type equations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn't a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: Is it not possible to evaluate this?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: the homeworks seems to be getting tougher today. I have to admit that I have no idea how to solve this problem...

Comment: @Fabian Perhaps I jumped the gun

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, I was able to obtain the following representation:

> \begin{align*}
> &\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2\left| \cot\left(\frac{\alpha x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right|}{x^4 + 4} \, dx \\
> &\hspace{3em} = \frac{1}{8}\sum_{\omega \ : \ \omega^4 = -4} \omega \left[ \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{\cos(\alpha \omega)}{\sin(\alpha\omega)+1}\right) + \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{\cos(\alpha \omega)}{\sin(\alpha\omega)-1}\right)  \right]. \tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Here the sum in the right-hand side runs over all $\omega$ such that $\omega^4 = -4$, i.e., $\omega = \pm 1 \pm i$. Also $\operatorname{Li}_3$ is the trilogarithm function. For instance, for $\alpha = 2$ we have

> [image]

But to be honest, I have no idea whether this simplifies further or not.

---

The idea is as follows: Let $I$ denote the integral.

1. It is not hard to check that $x \mapsto \log^2\left| \cot\left(\frac{\alpha x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right|$ is an even $\frac{\pi}{\alpha}$-periodic function. So

   \begin{align*}
   I
   &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2\left| \cot\left(\frac{\alpha x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right|}{x^4 + 4} \, dx \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}}^{\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}} \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x - \frac{k\pi}{\alpha})^4 + 4} \right) \log^2\left| \cot\left(\frac{\alpha x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right| \, dx  \\
   &= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}} \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x - \frac{k\pi}{\alpha})^4 + 4} \right) \log^2\left| \cot\left(\frac{\alpha x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right| \, dx. \tag{2}
   \end{align*}
2. We have the following partial fraction decomposition

   $$ \frac{1}{x^4 + 4} = -\frac{1}{16} \sum_{\omega \ : \ \omega^4 = -4} \frac{\omega}{x - \omega}. $$

   Using this decomposition and the partial fraction decomposition of cotangent, we find that

   $$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x - \frac{k\pi}{\alpha})^4 + 4} = -\frac{\alpha}{16} \sum_{\omega \ : \ \omega^4 = -4} \omega \cot(\alpha x - \alpha \omega). \tag{3} $$
3. Apply the substitution $u = \log \cot \left( \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\alpha x}{2} \right)$, assuming that $\alpha > 0$. Then it is easy to check that

   $$ \tan(\alpha x) = \sinh u, \qquad dx = \frac{du}{\alpha \cosh u}.$$

   Putting this and $\text{(2)-(3)}$ altogether, we obtain

   $$ I = -\frac{1}{16} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^2 \left( \sum_{\omega \ : \ \omega^4 = -4}  \frac{\omega \cosh u}{\sinh u - \tan(\alpha \omega)} \right) \, du. \tag{4} $$
4. With $A_{\pm}(\omega) = \frac{\cos(\alpha \omega)}{\sin(\alpha \omega) \pm 1}$, we can check that

   \begin{align*}
   -\sum_{\omega \ : \ \omega^4 = -4} \frac{\omega \cosh u}{\sinh u - \tan(\alpha \omega)}
   &= \sum_{\omega \ : \ \omega^4 = -4} \omega \left( \frac{1}{1 - A_+(\omega) e^{-u}} + \frac{1}{1 - A_-(\omega) e^{-u}} \right) \\
   &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{\omega \ : \ \omega^4 = -4} \omega( A_+(\omega)^n + A_-(\omega)^n) \right) e^{-nu}.
   \end{align*}

   Plugging this back to $\text{(4)}$ and simplifying using the gamma integral yields the desired identity $\text{(1)}$.

Comment: This is a wonderful derivation, you are truly a genius, thank you Sangchul lee sir.